# Orbit of a subgroup

Tags: group-theory, group-actions

$G$ is a group acting on $S$. $H$ is a subgroup of $G$ and let $s$ be anything in $S$. Is it true that the size of the orbit of $s$ under action of $G$ is divisible by the size of the orbit of $s$ under action of $H$?

Comment: Can you tell us what you've already tried?  And what concepts/techniques/theoerems you think might be involved?

Comment: that its true if every action of G is unique. $|G|$/$|G_s|$=$m|H|/k|H_s|$

Comment: The stabilizer $H_s$ of $s$ in $H$ is exactly the intersection $G_s \cap H$. So your statement is reduced to ask if $[H \cap G:H \cap G_s] / [G:G_s]$. Any ideas on how to go further?

Answer (score 4):

If *G* is the symmetric group on *n* letters, then the orbit of *s* has exactly *n* elements. Saying that *H* ≤ *G* means that *H* is a permutation group on *n* letters.  Does every permutation group on *n* letters have orbits that are divisors of *n*?

Perhaps check *n* = 3 to start.  A similar investigation *n* = 5 should also be instructive.